# div tags within a div tag positioning

Tags: html, css, css-float

since days I try to position 4 div tags (accommodation site widgets) within a div tag so that they are showing in one horizontal line side by side. I used the CSS elements "float" and "display" to do this but of whatever reason only 2 of the 4 divs position the way I want to. You can see the result here http://www.somersetsights.co.za/preiseneu.html. The css style elements are either inline style in the html document or in the style sheet http://www.somersetsights.co.za/css/style.css.

I am not a expert. Actually rather inexperienced. I tried hard to solve this by myself but I struggle. I hope a expert can advice me. Thanks

Comment: You forgot to add css in `#booking_com_widget` like other divs and also there are image not found in this.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this help you. add this CSS to your outer div

```
#review_widgets {
display: table-cell;
width: 1%;}
```

This will make your div horizontal

Comment: Thanks, I will check

Comment: @afrikapit, Did this answer your question? If so, accept it. It's the checkmark on the answer. This allows devs with a similar question to go straight to a solution. If not, add a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this. For example you can set the width to 100% to the `.services` div that it's actually the parent tag of that content you want inline. Personally I would use `display: inline-block`to position the elements instead of floats but it depends on you.
Also I would assign `box-sizing: border-box` to the `.services` tag for avoid the overflow of that div due to its padding.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I will check